# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i am using flash CS 5.5.if i call one function in button click event by the time that error came.Anyone say what am doing wrong?

This my code:

```
var visited:Object = {
    Movieclip: 0,
    one: 0,
    two: 0,
    three: 0,
    four: 0,
    five: 0,
    six: 0,
    seven7: 0
};

function saveCourseStatus():void 
{

    var suspend_str:String = visited.Movieclip + "," + visited.one + "," + visited.two + "," + visited.three + "," + visited.four + "," + visited.five + "," + visited.six + "," + visited.seven;
    scorm.set("cmi.suspend_data", suspend_str);
    scorm.save();
}

Newbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Nxt);

function Nxt(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    saveCourseStatus();
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(0, "one");
}
```

i have this error.saveCourseStatus();

```
peError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at New_fla::MainTimeline/saveCourseStatus()[New_fla.MainTimeline::frame98:116]
    at New_fla::MainTimeline/Nxt()[New_fla.MainTimeline::frame98:125]
```

Comment: What is `visited.MovieClip`? Also, check if `visited` or `scorm` is null in there.

Comment: What is scrom ? did you create it before somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that either "scorn" or "visited" is null. Flash throws an error if you try to get a property or method of an object that is null. Both scorm and visited have a strong possibility of not being available to the saveCourseStatus function depending on how you defined and how your entire code is set up. Since you don't pass them as parameters to saveCourseStatus they would need to be public variables for saveCourseStatus to access them.

In addition, your object property is named "seven7" (note the "7")while you try to call it in as "visited.seven" in saveCourseStatus

Comment: Voted down. The Flash runtime does not throw error if: 'you try to get a property or method of an object that is null'. That's a false statment that shows that you don't understand what is going on at all. A non instantiated complex object is of type 'null' (yes null is a type just like MovieClip or String), object of type null have no property or methods so trying to access anything on object of type null result in error.

Comment: When I run this: "var obj:Object; 
trace(obj.prop);", I get this error: "TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference." which is Flash throwing an error when I I try to get get a property of the null object. Is this a matter of semantics? I'm just trying to help the OP. Did you have an answer for the OP?

Comment: I don't answer null question as they are for beginner only. Your reply still shows that you do not understand what's an object of type null. It's not a matter of semantic, null is a type not a state.